# Mongodb: limit 2-level nested document

Tags: mongodb

Mongod deb albums collection contains such items:

```
var album = {
    name: 'album1',
    tracks: [{
        title: 'track0',
        language: 'en',
        processing: {
            tasks: [
               {_id: 1, name: 'someTask1'},
               {_id: 2, name: 'someTask2'},
            ]
        }


    },{
        title: 'track1',
        language: 'en',
    },{
        title: 'track2',
        language: 'es',
    }]
}
```

I need to select only one Album, track0 and task with _id 1, so that result set would be looking like (contains only one track and only one task)

```
{
    name: 'album1'
    tracks: [{
        title: 'track0',
        language: 'en',
        processing: {
            tasks: [
               {_id: 1, name: 'someTask1', },
            ]
        }
   ]
}
```

Is it possible to that without aggregation framework just using find?

I tried $elemMatch and .$ projection to limit output, but it seems that it doesn't work on nested levels > 1 (tasks in that case) =(

Comment: see my comment about schema design in your other question about querying this collection.

Comment: Thanks, I reconsidered the schema, moved processing tasks away to separate collection.